# Year of reference in brackets in Latex

Tags: reference, latex

I use **\textcite{}** and **\parencite{}** for referencing in a latex file. Using that method, I get as default; *Author (Year)*... and *(Author, Year)*. But I would like to adjust the **\parencite{}**  reference as *(Author (Year))* as the standard method in the Journal of Finance.

This would be a sample bibliography:

```
@article{examplesource,
      title={Title of article},
      author={LastName1, FirstName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3},
      journal={Journal of Finance},
      volume={40},
      number={1},
      pages={3--73},
      year={2005}}
```

And this is what I got so far (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379901/biblatex-how-to-match-the-journal-of-finance-bibliographic-style):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\begin{document}
\textcite{examplesource} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{examplesource}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `ext-authoryear` style, you can change the delimiter using `\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}


\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{knuth:ct}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot:) In addition; what do I have to change to replace the brackets with commas for the years in the reference section?

Comment: @fjurt If you have a new question, please use the ask question button to ask a new question